# How to change Image & content using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I just have an HTML page with an image & Content.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td height="240" valign="top" colspan="3">
<img id="image" class="newsimage" src="D:/Search/images/search.jpg" alt="search" height="120" width="50%"/>
<div class="imageContect">image Content</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below it I have 2 links of previous & next.

```
<a href="#" onclick="">Previous</a>
<a href="#" onclick="">Next</a>
```

I want to change image of "image" id & content of "imageContent" id using AJAX (javaScript).

What are the Steps I should follow ?

Comment: I think you don't need to use any ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think something like

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var newsImageData = [
            {src: "D:/Search/images/search1.jpg", data: "image content1"},
            {src: "D:/Search/images/search2.jpg", data: "image content2"},
            {src: "D:/Search/images/search3.jpg", data: "image content3"}
        ];

        var currNewsImgIdx = 0;

        function UpdateNews () {
            var img = document.getElementById ("image");
            var imgContent = document.getElementById ("imageContent");

            img.src = newsImageData[currNewsImgIdx].src;
            imgContent.innerHTML = newsImageData[currNewsImgIdx].data;
        }

        function NextNews () {
            currNewsImgIdx = (currNewsImgIdx + 1) % newsImageData.length;
            UpdateNews ();
        }

        function PrevNews () {
            currNewsImgIdx = (currNewsImgIdx + newsImageData.length - 1) % newsImageData.length;
            UpdateNews ();
        }

        function OnDocLoad () {
            UpdateNews ();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnDocLoad ()">
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td height="240" valign="top" colspan="3"> 
                <img id="image" class="newsimage" src="" alt="search" height="120" width="50%"/> 
                <div id="imageContent" class="imageContent"></div> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 

    <a href="#" onclick="PrevNews ()">Previous</a>       
    <a href="#" onclick="NextNews ()">Next</a>     

</body>
```

Related links:
[onload event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljawbmqm.php),
[getElementById method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrkpkbi.php),
[innerHTML property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdkwhqf.php),
[src property (image)](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhipejg.php)

Comment: Somthing Problem, image is not getting changed.

Comment: Use relative paths instead of full paths (images/search1.jpg instead of D:/Search/images/search1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript_image_change_functions.php3) to see how you can change the source of an image.

To change the content of the DIV, give it an ID and use JavaScript to change its innerHTML